# How to block variable persistence in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor

I have a simple page like that

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach(user in Users)
    {
        <tr>
            <th>@user.Id</th>
            <th>@user.Name</th>
            <th>@user.Age</th>
            <th><button type="button" @onclick="() => EditUser(user)">Edit</button></th>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code
{
    var Users = GetUsers(); // Fetch a list of users
    private void EditUser(User user)
    {
        var selectedUser = user;
        selectedUser.Name = "Changed";
    }
}
```

When my var selectedUser get userData it is persisting on user inside the list, i mean when the selectedUser.Name is setted to "Change" the user inside the list also changes, but i dont want to do that until the user click on a save button for example. So how to get all the user data but not persist when change. My idea following the save button example is after the save i get the user from the list using linq or index whatever and set the object there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way: Install AutoMapper

Note I would normally set up the Mapper as an injected service.

```
private void EditUser(User user)
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<User, User>());
    var mapper = new Mapper(config);
    var selectedUser = new User();
    mapper.Map<User, User>(user, selectedUser);
    selectedUser.Name = "Changed";
}
```

> When my var selectedUser get userData it is persisting on user inside the list.

This is because `var selectedUser = user;` makes `selectedUser` a reference to the same class.

Alternatively if you can modify the User class you could use the protected `MemberwiseClone` function to make a shallow copy of the class.